# how to change the column name

Tags: sqlite

I am using 2 tables, `dockmanagementtable` and `dockinfotable`.
And I am using the following command for calculating the elapsed time:

```
((((dockmanagementtable.setvalueh * 60*60) +
   (dockmanagementtable.setvaluem * 60)) -
  dockinfotable.elapsedsecs)/60)
```

I am getting the correct output correctly. But I cannot modify the column name, which displays as `((((dockmanagementtable.setvalueh * 60*60) +(dockmanagementtable.setvaluem * 60)) - dockinfotable.elapsedsecs)/60)`.

I need to change that column name while doing the same operation.

My command is as follows:

```
select ((((dockmanagementtable.setvalueh * 60*60) +
          (dockmanagementtable.setvaluem * 60)) -
         dockinfotable.elapsedsecs)/60)
from dockinfotable inner join dockmanagementtable;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an alias to the column output in sql selection.

```
select ((((dockmanagementtable.setvalueh * 60*60) + 
(dockmanagementtable.setvaluem * 60)) - dockinfotable.elapsedsecs)/60) as 
mycolumn from dockinfotable inner join dockmanagementtable;
```

Or

```
select ((((dockmanagementtable.setvalueh * 60*60) + 
(dockmanagementtable.setvaluem * 60)) - dockinfotable.elapsedsecs)/60) 
mycolumn from dockinfotable inner join dockmanagementtable;
```